# How to import js file as string with Rollup?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

In Webpack, we have raw-loader to import files like .js as strings. I'm using Rollup. Does Rollup has anything similar to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, you need a plugin for that.

I found one today https://github.com/TrySound/rollup-plugin-string